# Use of Rtti ParamType

Tags: delphi

Assume we have the following code fragment:

```
TMyType = Pointer;

TMyClass = class
    procedure myMethod (argument : TMyType);
end;
```

I've been using Rtti to reflect on such a class so that I can write out the method signature including the argument type. However when I use Rtti on this I get:

```
TMyClass = class
    procedure myMethod (argument : Pointer);
end;
```

That is instead of getting the name TMyType, I get Pointer. I am using ParamType.name to get the name of the argument type.

My question is, is there anyway to get the name of the type the developer actually declared the argument to be, ie TMyType? Since ParamType.name doesn't return the expected type name I am assuming that types that are not declared in a class have no Rtti information?

Using Delphi XE

Comment: Declare a type instead of an alias `TMytype = type Pointer`

Comment: The reason being that the compiler resolves aliases to their base types before creating the RTTI, that is why you see `Pointer` instead of `TMyType`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Sertac Akyuz and Remy Lebeau both answered the question. I provide the answer below:

Declare a type instead of an alias TMytype = type Pointer